# Making a local and production database connection when deploying a Sinatra app to Heroku

Tags: ruby, database, postgresql, heroku

I have a sinatra app that needs to use a database, and within my app I have a class 'Admin' that handles all database things. I need 'Admin' to make a connection to the local database file if I am running locally, but connect to the Heroku postgres database when running online. I've followed instructions [here](http://jgtr.github.io/blog/2013/07/28/deploying-a-sqlite3-database-to-heroku-for-production-using-postgres/) but while it has gotten me far, I don't know how to add my database connections to my class. I believe it to be a very simple question that I don't know the answer to. Here is my class that handles the application's database connection

```
require 'sequel'
require 'pg'

#This class will handle making the database
class Admin

#A getter/setter for DB
attr_accessor :DB

#Our constructor that makes the database and tables we need
def initialize
    configure :development do
        set :@DB, "sqlite://database.db"
    end

    configure :production do
        @DB = URI.parse(ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || 'postgres://localhost/mydb')

        ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
            :adapter  => @DB.scheme == 'postgres' ? 'postgresql' : @DB.scheme,
            :host     => @DB.host,
            :username => @DB.user,
            :password => @DB.password,
            :database => @DB.path[1..-1],
            :encoding => 'utf8'
        )
    end

    #@DB = Sequel.connect('sqlite://database.db')# || ENV['DATABASE_URL'])
end

#.....
end
```

I just need Admin.DB to hold either a local or online reference to the database (if I understand everything correctly)

Comment: where you initialized your class using the `.new`?or you are using `Admin.DB`?

Comment: I initialize my class as so 'admin = Admin.new' in my main ruby file